# Soap Webservice Response Differing on Tomcat 9 and Java 11

Tags: java, xml, soap, java-11, tomcat9

I am migrating my application to Java 11 and Tomcat 9 from Java 8 and Tomcat 7. 
With some version updates, minor implementation changes and adding few maven dependencies, I have been able to successfully compile and run my application. However, I have few integration tests written to test the Soap based webservices in my application which are failing. 
This is happening due to mismatch in the expected Soap response and the actual response.

Here are the two responses: 
Actual is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<S:Envelope
xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">    
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>    
<S:Body
    xmlns:ns2="http://www.acd.org/cact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader"
    xmlns:ns3="urn:global:cpci-query:xsd:1"
    xmlns:ns4="urn:global:cpci-masterdata:xsd:1"
    xmlns:ns5="urn:global:cpci:xsd:1">        
    <ns3:GetResult>            
    <string>SimpleDataQuery</string>
    <string>SimpleQuery</string>                    
    </ns3:GetResult>    
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Expected is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">    
<soapenv:Body>                
    <ns5:GetResult
        xmlns:ns5="urn:global:cpci-query:xsd:1">                        
        <string>SimpleQuery</string>                        
        <string>SimpleDataQuery</string>                    
    </ns5:GetResult>            
</soapenv:Body>    
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The pom  has following updated entries :

```
 <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>

            </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Can there be any impact of Java 11 on WS responses' elements order being disturbed ? If yes, then is this due to some outdated dependencies or we need to modify some implementations?

Comment: Hi, in Java 11 some API's are removed - `java.activation , java.corba, java.transaction ,java.xml.bind  << This one contains the JAXB APIs
java.xml.ws, java.xml.ws.annotation`. So we have to use some 3rd party dependency during migrating from old version of java. The impact depends only upon the 3rd party jar. Choose the best jar to achieve your requirement

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, I have completed these steps and application is running. The only issue now, is the order of the elements  in my SOAP base web service response  is not what it used to be with Java 8.

Comment: On XML level the old and the actual response are the same, the Java 11 version is just not optimized as it contains unused namespaces.

Comment: I agree with @Robert, the XML's content is the same. Maybe this is an opportunity to make the integration tests less strict, so they ignore the XML's form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update : Apparently the issue was due to rt.jar and jaxws-rt.jar missing in the new JDKs. Adding these dependencies doesn't solve the problem totally as their transitive are not available due to non compilation of their pom.xml.
Adding all the required transitive dependencies in the maven solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Though I am not sure if this is the right solution but the following worked for me :

Explicitly added following entries in my pom.xml (these are old dependencies as the newer ones are causing xml responses to change) :

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
       <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.8</version>
       <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
       <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
       <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream.buffer</groupId>
       <artifactId>streambuffer</artifactId>
       <version>1.5.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal</groupId>
       <artifactId>resolver</artifactId>
       <version>20050927</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.gmbal</groupId>
       <artifactId>gmbal</artifactId>
       <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
       <artifactId>rt-ha</artifactId>
       <version>2.3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Post these changes, I am getting the XML responses same as I was getting on Java 8 before migrating to Java 11.